# How to make add break  after paragraph in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

i want to ask. How to add break after paragraph in **one text field**.
for example,

A report is a textual work (usually of writing, speech, television, or film) made with the specific intention of relaying information.

**To be like this:-**

```
"A report is a textual work  line 1

(usually of writing, speech, television, or film) line 2

 made with the specific intention of line 3

 relaying information" line 4
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use *`\n`* (newline) symbols or you can use the markup syntax.

The sample:

```xml
<title>
    <band height="167" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="414" y="38" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement markup="styled"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["A report is a textual work <br/>(usually of writing, speech, television, or film) <br/>made with the specific intention of <br/> relaying information"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="26" y="38" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["A report is a textual work\n(usually of writing, speech, television, or film)\nmade with the specific intention of \nrelaying information"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
```

More information about using styled text [is here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/styledtext/index.html#styledtext).