# ireports paragraph merged with data from fields

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

What report element should I use to insert a paragraph of my text that has data fields in parts of the paragraph?  Simply a mail merge style letter is what I am needing to accomplish from iReport of JasperReports.
I have tried the Text Field element but get the following error:

```
"Dear "+$F{fname}+",

Thanks for your business.  We have applied your recent payment of "+$F{pmt}+" to your account.

Sincerely,
Customer Service"
```

ERROR:

startup failed: calculator_PD30Letter_1346189028106_871925: 171: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 171, column 75. 1 error

Also, if advisable, where can I find this line and column referenced so that I may be able to self help in the future as I use Jasper more?

Comment: You can read my answer on [How to make add break  after paragraph in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10070546/876298) question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make add break  after paragraph in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069897/how-to-make-add-break-after-paragraph-in-jasper-reports)

Answer (score 0):

You hav it almost.  The problem is the text field does not seem to like the /n  (return/enters).   To get around this problem I change the markup of the field to html and use the  br   in place of the enters after the , on the first line and after the . And , at the end

Comment: Changed the Markup as html. I added <br> and tried </br> but neither one will work. 
"Dear "+$F{CFNA1}+",</br> Thanks for your business. We have applied your recent payment of "$F{PDDAYS}" to your account.</br> Sincerely,</br> Customer Service"</br> ERROR 171: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 171, column 80. Where can I find the file that this line/column is referring?