# JasperReports - Can I insert the expression into static text

Tags: jasper-reports

I have the such fragment of JR's report (*jrxml* file):

```xml
<band height="110">
     <staticText>
     <reportElement style="disclaimer" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="10" width="522" height="100"/>
     <textElement markup="styled"/>
    <text>
$P{settings}.getData()
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do   eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </text>
    </staticText>
    </band>
```

Question is that: How can I insert expression `$P{settings}.getData()` in static text ?

I know the way to it, using `<textFieldExpression>`, but in this case my text is broken by the space, therefore it looks not nice.

Comment: You can't use expression in *staticText*. You should use the *textField* element. You can use markup; you can look at [Style a text field in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8135922/876298)  & [How to make add break after paragraph in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10070546/876298) posts

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make add break  after paragraph in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069897/how-to-make-add-break-after-paragraph-in-jasper-reports)